# Open MPI Sending structure C

Tags: c, data-structures, mpi

Is it possible to send a structure as a datatype in Open MPI?

Comment: You can cast it to an array of bytes (char*)

Comment: What do you mean by 'send'?  Call a C function from MPI and pass a structure?  Vice versa?  Or transferring data over the wire?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, have a look first at `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT`, or if your implementation does not include MPI-2 features, the older `MPI_TYPE_STRUCT`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'll need to define a new MPI datatype that desribes the memory layout of your struct. More info [here](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node79.html#SECTION00436000000000000000).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C and your cluster uses the same hardware on every node you can memcopy the structs in and out of an MPI_BYTE array when passing them around. You do have to be careful of offsets and endian issues. Works for one of "script" type programs but you would never want to do this in production unless you had a standard API for marshalling.